# Data handling with seekp() and tellg()

Tags: c++, pointers

It's a long program, so it will be difficult for me to type in everything.I'm confused at this particular part of the program;

```
int Filepos=File.tellg();
File.seekp(Filepos-sizeof(ITEM),ios::beg);
```

I'm okay with the first line but I'm totally confused with the hyphen in the second line, help me out plz.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I only need to know the use of that hyphen, I'm ok with everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filepos "minus" sizeof(...). Sets the output position indicator to the value of the "subtraction", the offset is from the beginning of the stream.

Comment: Oh, it was minus.Sorry.